# WooCommerce Update Product Variation Stock Status based on Quantities of other Variation's Stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good day,

I have a product with 4 variations (variations made from the 'size' attribute): Small, Medium, Large and Full Set (all 3 sizes). People can choose to buy only a single size or buy a set that has all 3 sizes (prices differ for all 4 variations).

I only have stock management (with backorders allowed) selected for the 3 size variations (small, medium, large) and for the Set variation I have only selected the stock status to be 'in stock'. I need to automatically change the Set variation stock status based on the stock quantities of the size variations.

When I have 1 Small, 1 Medium and 1 Large, I obviously also have a Set in stock. But, for instance, when someone buys the small one, then I do not have a full Set anymore. I would like to automatically update the stock status of the Set variation to 'on backorder'. Also, the other way around would be, when someone buys a full Set to automatically update the stock quantities of Small, Medium & Large with -1.

```
SMALL - 1x in stock
MEDIUM - 1x in stock
LARGE - 1x in stock
FULL SET - stock status: 'in stock' (only 'in-stock' when there is at least 1 of each; small, medium, large)
```

When someone buys a full set:

```
SMALL - 1x in stock -1 = 0x in stock
MEDIUM - 1x in stock -1 = 0x in stock
LARGE - 1x in stock -1 = 0x in stock
FULL SET - stock status: 'on backorder' (only 'in-stock' when there is at least 1 of each; small, medium, large)
```

All of the products make use of these variations and they will not change.

Dummy code will probably be something like (this will in no way work, I was just trying to put something together from a lot of internet searches):

**To set the Full Set stock status:**

```
function fullset_custom_stockstatus (){
    global $product;
    // Get the available variations
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    // Get the term slugs
    $attribute_slug = $values['attributes']['attribute_pa_headcover-size'];
    $wp_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $attribute_slug, 'pa_headcover-size' );
    $term_slug = $wp_term->slug; // Headcover Size Slug 

    // Get the variation quantity
    $variation_obj = wc_get_product( $values['variation_id'] );
    $stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity(); // Stock qty

    //Seperate variation stock data
    $var_small = $term_slug['small'].$stock_qty;
    $var_medium = $term_slug['medium'].$stock_qty;
    $var_large = $term_slug['large'].$stock_qty;

    $var_fullset = $term_name['full-set'].$stock_status;
    
    //Check if each variation stock is 1 or more
    if ($var_small == 0 || $var_medium == 0 || $var_large == 0){
        $var_fullset = 'on-backorder';
    }
    else{
        $var_fullset = 'in-stock';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', 'fullset_custom_stockstatus');
```

**To update the variation quantities when a full set was bought:**

```
function update_stockqty_after_fullset_order (){

    //Get the order information
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        $order_product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $order_variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();

        //Get the order variation information
        $order_variation = wc_get_product($order_variation_id);
        $order_variation_attribs = $order_variation->get_variation_attributes();
        
        //Check if order variation is 'full-set'
        if ($order_variation_attribs !== 'full-set' ){

            //Get the order product variation information
            $product = wc_get_product( $order_product_id );
            $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

            // Get the term slugs
            $attribute_slug = $values['attributes']['attribute_pa_headcover-size'];
            $wp_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $attribute_slug, 'pa_headcover-size' );
            $term_slug = $wp_term->slug; // Headcover Size Slug 

            // Get the variation quantity
            $variation_obj = wc_get_product( $values['variation_id'] );
            $stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity(); // Stock qty

            //Seperate variation stock data
            $var_small = $term_slug['small'].$stock_qty;
            $var_medium = $term_slug['medium'].$stock_qty;
            $var_large = $term_slug['large'].$stock_qty;

            //Update the stock quanities
            wc_update_product_stock( $var_small, 'decrease' ); 
            wc_update_product_stock( $var_medium, 'decrease' ); 
            wc_update_product_stock( $var_large, 'decrease' ); 

            // Clear/refresh the variation cache (optionally if needed)
            wc_delete_product_transients($variation['variation_id']);

        } else {
         return;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'update_stockqty_after_fullset_order');
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`woocommerce_order_status_processing`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.363) hook which is activated when the order status is changed to **wc-processing**.

#### UPDATED

The "full-set" variation is updated only if:

1. at least one "small", "medium" or "large" variation was purchased
2. the smallest stock quantity of the "small", "medium" and "large" variations is less than the stock quantity of the "full-set" variation

In this way the stock quantity of the "full-set" variation **will be equal to the minimum salable quantity** based on the stock quantities of the "small", "medium" and "large" variations.

When the stock quantity of the "full-set" variation is less than or equal to zero, **it enables back orders**.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'update_stock_quantity_product', 999, 2 );
function update_stock_quantity_product( $order_id, $order ) {

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data ) {

        $product = $item_data->get_product();

        // only if the product is a variation
        if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        // initializes the array that will contain the quantity stocks of "small", "medium" and "large" products
        $min_stock = array();

        $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes(); // get the variation attributes
        foreach ( $variation_attributes as $attribute_value ) {
            switch ( $attribute_value ) {
                case 'small':
                    $min_stock[] = $product->get_stock_quantity();
                    break;
                case 'medium':
                    $min_stock[] = $product->get_stock_quantity();
                    break;
                case 'large':
                    $min_stock[] = $product->get_stock_quantity();
                    break;
            }
        }

        $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes(); // get the variation attributes
        foreach ( $variation_attributes as $attribute_value ) {
            // check attribute value
            switch ( $attribute_value ) {
                case 'small':
                case 'medium':
                case 'large':
                    $qty = $item_data->get_quantity(); // get ordered quantity
                    $variable = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() ); // get variable product
                    $variation_ids = $variable->get_children();
                    foreach ( $variation_ids as $variation_id ) {
                        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
                        $attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();
                        foreach ( $attributes as $value ) {
                            if ( $value == 'full-set' ) {
                                if ( ! empty( $min_stock ) ) { // if is not empty
                                    // get the minimum value of the array
                                    $new_stock = min( $min_stock );
                                    // get the stock quantity of the "full-set" variation
                                    $stock = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
                                    // updates the stock quantity only if the minimum availability of the "small", "medium" and "large" variations
                                    // is less than the availability of the "full-set" variation
                                    if ( $new_stock < $stock ) {
                                        if ( $new_stock > 0 ) {
                                            $variation->set_stock_quantity( $new_stock );
                                            $variation->set_stock_status( 'instock' ); 
                                            $variation->save(); // save the data and refresh caches
                                        } else {
                                            $variation->set_stock_quantity( 0 );
                                            $variation->set_stock_status( 'outofstock' );
                                            $variation->set_backorders( 'yes' );
                                            $variation->save(); // save the data and refresh caches
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'full-set':
                        $qty = $item_data->get_quantity(); // get ordered quantity
                        $variable = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() ); // get variable product
                        $variation_ids = $variable->get_children();
                        foreach ( $variation_ids as $variation_id ) {
                            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
                            $attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();
                            foreach ( $attributes as $value ) {
                                switch ( $value ) {
                                    case 'small':
                                    case 'medium':
                                    case 'large':
                                        $stock = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
                                        $new_stock = $stock - $qty;
                                        if ( $new_stock > 0 ) {
                                            $variation->set_stock_quantity( $new_stock );
                                            $variation->set_stock_status( 'instock' ); 
                                            $variation->save(); // save the data and refresh caches
                                        } else {
                                            $variation->set_stock_quantity( 0 );
                                            $variation->set_stock_status( 'outofstock' );
                                            $variation->save(); // save the data and refresh caches
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case 'full-set':
                                        $stock = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
                                        $new_stock = $stock - $qty;
                                        if ( $new_stock <= 0 ) {
                                            // enables backorders for the "full-set" product if the stock quantity is less than or equal to zero
                                            $variation->set_backorders( 'yes' );
                                            $variation->save(); // save the data and refresh caches
                                        }
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested the code and it works. The code goes into your theme's functions.php.

Comment: Thank you very much @Vdgaetano! This is great but although the code works as expected it unfortunately is not a real working solution. For instance: what about when I have 4x small, 4x medium, 4x large = 4x full sets, and someone buys 1x small and another customer buys 1x medium, each of these transactions will decrease the quantity of full sets, setting the quantity at only 2 full sets left but I actually still have 3 full sets.

Comment: As addition to my previous comment: This is why I thought it best to not do stock quantity management for the full sets (it is also not really necessary because my sets just comprises of the quantiies of small, medium and large I have), but rather just check if there is at least 1 of each small, medium, large and toggle the full set variation from in-stock if there is and if there is not atleast 1 of each size in stock to toggle it to on-backorder.

Comment: @Stander I have updated my response based on your request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Vdgaetano's code I could have get the code to fit my needs. Thank you again @Vdgaetano - you are awesome! :-)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'update_stock_quantity_product', 999999, 2 );
function update_stock_quantity_product( $order_id, $order ) {

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data ) {

        $product = $item_data->get_product();

        // only if the product is a variation
        if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes(); // get the variation attributes
        foreach ( $variation_attributes as $attribute_value ) {
            // check attribute value
            switch ( $attribute_value ) {
                case 'small':
                case 'medium':
                case 'large':
                    $qty = $item_data->get_quantity(); // get ordered quantity
                    $variable = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() ); // get variable product
                    $variation_ids = $variable->get_children();
                    foreach ( $variation_ids as $variation_id ) {
                        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
                        $attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();
                        foreach ( $attributes as $value ) {
                            if ( $value == 'small' ) {
                                $smallstock = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
                            }
                            if ( $value == 'medium' ) {
                                $mediumstock = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
                            }
                            if ( $value == 'large' ) {
                                $largestock = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
                            }
                            if ( $value == 'full-set' ) {
                                if ( $smallstock == 0 || $mediumstock == 0 || $largestock == 0) {                                    
                                    $variation->set_stock_status( 'onbackorder' ); 
                                    $variation->save(); // save the data and refresh caches
                                } else {                                    
                                    $variation->set_stock_status( 'instock' );
                                    $variation->save(); // save the data and refresh caches
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'full-set':
                        $qty = $item_data->get_quantity(); // get ordered quantity
                        $variable = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() ); // get variable product
                        $variation_ids = $variable->get_children();
                        foreach ( $variation_ids as $variation_id ) {
                            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
                            $attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();
                            foreach ( $attributes as $value ) {
                                switch ( $value ) {
                                    case 'small':
                                    case 'medium':
                                    case 'large':
                                        $stock = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
                                        $new_stock = $stock - $qty;
                                        if ( $new_stock > 0 ) {
                                            $variation->set_stock_quantity( $new_stock );
                                            $variation->set_stock_status( 'instock' ); 
                                            $variation->save(); // save the data and refresh caches
                                        } else {
                                            $variation->set_stock_quantity( 0 );
                                            $variation->set_stock_status( 'outofstock' );
                                            $variation->save(); // save the data and refresh caches
                                        }
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```